# Wie bekommt man das rollende r weg?

Tags: pronunciation

Das rollende "r" ist etwas, woran man erkennt, dass man mit einem Nicht-muttersprachler redet, egal wie gut dieser spricht. Im Grunde ist das kein großes Problem, doch bei Wörtern wie "Regen" "Brief" fällt das schon auf. Ich habe schon einige Seiten durchforstet und finde dabei keine genaue Lösung. Deswegen suche ich nach einer Seite, wo das erklärt ist, oder schlicht einem Ratschlag, wie man das "r" richtig ausspricht.

Comment: Ganz genau genommen gibt es zwei "deutsche r": das vokalisierte "r", und das "r", das du beschreibst. Und seit wann ist das rollende "r" ein *Fehler*?

Comment: Am rollenden "r" ist nichts falsch. Können alle Franken bestätigen.

Comment: Auch Nicht-Franken werden das bestätigen.

Comment: Wir hatten sogar eine Fernsehansagerin (Caroline Reiber) mit rollendem R: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5N25RfnvzQ

Comment: Die Frage _»Wie kriege ich mein rollendes R weg?«_ klingt für einen Franken ähnlich wie _»Wie verbrenne ich meine weißblaue Bettwäsche?«_.

Comment: @Pollitzer Hat der Franke nicht eher rot-weiße Bettwäsche?

Comment: @Pollitzer: Einen Schluck Benzin drauf, und rauf, auf den Holzkohlegrill (nicht in geschlossenen 4 Wänden).

Comment: @Uwe: Ja, wenn man die [_Frankenfahne_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenfahne) zugrunde legt (deren Existenz mir nicht bekannt war).

Comment: Manche lernen sogar das rollende R, weil es Bestandteil der deutschen Bühnenaussprache ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Du misst die Benzin-Menge in Schlucken? Ist das nicht ungesund?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Erfahrene Feuerschlucker sagen: "Ja, doch, auf die Dauer schon." Und wer wäre ich, denen zu widersprechen? Aber wieviele Bettwäschen hat so ein typischer Franke?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Prämisse, die dieser Frage zugrundegelegt wird, ist schlichtweg unzutreffend. Das rollende R ist keineswegs ein Sprachfehler, sondern eine der drei Arten auf Deutsch den Konsonanten R auszusprechen.

Die drei Laute ​[⁠r⁠]​, ​[⁠ʀ⁠] und ​[⁠ʁ⁠] können im Deutschen beliebig ausgetauscht werden​. Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophon Abschnitt »Freie Variation« im Kapitel Arten von Allophonen.

Die folgenden sechs Varianten für das Wort »Regen« sind alle erlaubt:

> [ˈreːɡn̩], [ˈreːɡŋ̩], [ˈʀeːɡn̩], [ˈʀeːɡŋ̩], [ˈʁeːɡn̩], [ˈʁeːɡŋ̩]

([n] und [ŋ] sind zwar keine Allophone, können nach g aber dennoch in den meisten Fällen gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden.)

Bei »Brief« gibt es drei Varianten:

> [briːf], [bʀiːf], [bʁiːf]

Davon ausgenommen sind natürlich Reduktionssilben, in denen die Buchstabenfolge *»er«* als Tiefschwa ausgesprochen wird. (Fenster = [ˈfɛnstɐ])

---

Links zu den Beschreibungen der relevanten Laute:

- [r]
  [Stimmhafter alveolarer Vibrant](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmhafter_alveolarer_Vibrant) (»gerolltes R« mit mehreren Zungenschlägen)
- [ʀ]
  [Stimmhafter uvularer Vibrant](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmhafter_uvularer_Vibrant) (am Gaumenzäpfchen gerolltes R)
- [ʁ]
  [Stimmhafter uvularer Frikativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmhafter_uvularer_Frikativ) (geriebenes, nicht gerolltes Zäpfchen‑R)
- [ɐ]
  [Fast offener Zentralvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal) (»Tiefschwa«) (»A-Schwa«) (»Lehrer-Schwa«)

Comment: Dennoch kann man ja die Frage, mit welchen Übungen man das rollende R ersetzen kann, beantworten. Meiner Meinung nach geht die Antwort damit eigentlich an der Frage vorbei...

Answer (score 4):

Wenn eine "Seite" auch ein YouTube-Video sein darf, dann ...

- LanguageSheep: [Aussprache von R im Deutschen/German pronunciation of R (learn German)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlf_S4P47oI): zeigt, wie man das R lernen kann, ausgehend vom CH. Man spricht zum Beispiel abwechselnd CHCHCH - RRRR - CHCHCH - usw.
- froehlichDeutsch: [Das deutsche R - The German r (Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5DgUuCIHc0): zeigt auch, wie man das R lernen kann, ausgehend vom CH. Dieses Video gibt aber mehr Beispiele und Übungen. Auch gurgeln wird als Übung empfohlen (habe ich aber nie als "Übung" gemacht).
- GermanSkills.com: [Challenge Deutsch lernen (Tag 7): R oder kein ER - Wie spreche ich es aus?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsR9j79IDVw): sehr langes Video (22 Minuten) mit Erklärungen und Übungen.

Muttersprachler ohne Lehrerausbildung oder Linguistikkenntnisse können nicht immer gut erklären, wie man das R genau ausspricht. Siehe das EasyGerman-Video [How to pronounce "R" in German | Easy German 174](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aJOsLVJp8U).

Answer (score 1):

Dieser Frage liegt eine falsche Prämisse zugrunde. Denn der deutsche Sprachraum war und ist ziemlich groß innerhalb Zentraleuropas. Hier treten (schon geographisch bedingt) sehr viele Sprachvarietäten des Deutschen auf und keine davon ist per se falsches oder richtiges Deutsch. Was als Norm gilt, haben wir einfach auf einen bestimmten Dialekt festgelegt, heutzutage oft umgangssprachlich "Hochdeutsch" genannt.

Natürlich, wenn man dem Tagesschau-Moderator lauscht, wird man kein gerolltes R hören. In bestimmten Dialekten, z. B. in Franken hingegen schon. Keines von beiden ist per se falsch oder richtig, auch wenn das manche denken. Leider denken wir hierzulande, man müsse dies verstecken oder wegtrainieren. Wir haben also in Deutschland - ein Land, dass eigentlich die längste Zeit mehrere Ländernflecken war - heute ein beinahe gestörte Verhältniss zum Dialekt. Es könnte ja gar Zeichen von schlechter Bildung sein - ein Vorurteil. Der Dialekt verrät zwar den ungefähren Abstammungsort des Sprechers, nicht aber dessen Bildung. In anderen Ländern, z. B. Großbritannien, wird das weniger verschleiert. Dort sprechen beispielweise ein gebürtiger Schotte auch mit einem leicht gerollten R, und müsste sich dafür auch nicht in London schämen.
Solang die Verständigung nicht gestört wird, gibt es nichts dagegen einzuwenden.